# Group of Integers as Union of Very Distinct Cosets

Tags: group-theory

In the group of integers, every subgroup has finite index, hence the group can be written as a union of finitely many cosets of some subgroups.

**Question:** Can we write $\mathbb{Z}$ as union of finitely many cosets of *distinct* proper subgroups?

---

I tried to find such a cover, but failed. The answer seems to be negative, but I couldn't prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example is given [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system):

$$\Bbb Z=2\Bbb Z\cup 3\Bbb Z\cup(1+4\Bbb Z)\cup(5+6\Bbb Z)\cup(7+12\Bbb Z).$$

Also see [Sun's survey](http://math.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/Cover.pdf) cited at the end of the article.

Comment: nice answer! I had seen a paper of Sun on "Combinatorial aspects of covers.." in which he had given a cover $\{1+2Z, 2+4Z, ... , 2^{k-1}+2^kZ, 2^kZ\}$; but last two cosets are of same subgroup.